# How I can override specific css styles from react big calendar

Tags: css, calendar, react-big-calendar

I use a react big calendar in sharePoint web part. So this styles from external css of big calendar hide my month calendar:

```
.rbc-month-row {
    display: flex; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and I get the following picture:
[image]
so when I disable this styles from chrome it's okay:
[image]
I try to disable this styles from my own css but it's doesn't work:

```
.rbc-month-row {
  overflow: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

So how I can disable this styles by other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is  to change flex-basis property to auto like this:

```
flex-basis: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to make sure that your css is included after the react big calendar css file like as below.
example :

```
1. react big calendar.css
2. <custom.css>.
```

If this is way then it will worked and make sure that other style may not affecting this classes.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I include both css files to my project. And other styles did not affecting this classes. But my overridden style doesn't  work :0